# Are any op amp configurations better for noise?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

Considering the fact that the noise is always modeled as a voltage source on the positive input, is there any configuration where you get lower noise gain than signal gain?

EDIT:

Found answer
[image]

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-047.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That app note has nothing to do with noise gain. Doesn't answer the question in the slightest. Apologies.

Comment: *is there any configuration where you get lower noise gain than signal gain?* No, the circuit cannot "know" what is signal and what is noise. So no circuit can amplify one more than the other. This is assuming your signal is at a certain frequency (or bandwidth) and the noise is at the same frequencies. Only if that is not the case (the frequencies are different) then it migth be possible to **attenuate** the noise. But that then treats noise and signal different based on their frequency.

Comment: Under the assertion that "noise is always *modeled* as a voltage source on the positive input", there is no feasible option. However, noise *arises* at locations other than the input, and there are techniques to cancel it across certain inverting amplifiers (see Razavi's *RF Microelectronics* text, chapter on LNA design). I'm struggling to adapt the technique to a complex structure as an op-amp, however. An edit to the question to better document your needs and assumptions would be very helpful.

Comment: A general rule I use is that the (thermal) noise of a resistor is proportional to its value: higher value resistor means more noise. So in general only circuits where the signal is handled using **low value** resistors, you would get low noise.

Comment: @nanofarad *I'm struggling to adapt the technique to a complex structure as an op-amp, however.* What helps me in that respect is that noise is **just a signal**. So the circuit treats noise in the same way as it would treat **any** signal. What is usually done is to calculate back all noise sources to one point (usually the input) and then add them up (with sum of squares). Then you know the noise at the input. You also know what signal you're applying at the input so calculating SNR becomes easy.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks and apologies for the ambiguous comment. I'm familiar with the noise analysis procedure. I'm specifically speaking to the fact that I cannot adapt the technique of noise-cancelling amplifier design to an unspecified op-amp circuit so I cannot give an answer (it could very well be infeasible since it could rely on assumptions made for LNA design that don't apply here, but I'm not sure).

Comment: If noise is always modeled as a voltage on the + input, why does just about every op-amp data sheet list equivalent noise input voltage **and** equivalent noise input _current_?  Are you _sure_ that noise is _always_ modeled as _just_ a voltage?

Comment: @TimWescott For my application, low source resistance means the current noise is mostly negligible. I'm still going to calculate it because it will never be 0. But my question was mostly regarding the fact that noise is often modeled as being a source on the + input

Comment: @nanofarad I've heard other people mention Razavi's noise text. It really doesn't help in this application much.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Good answer, however you assume the noise is all summed back to one point. If that point is the + input rather than the - input that noise source won't see the same gain as a signal source on the - input. That is the key point I am trying to address, the model of the "noise source" and its position in the circuit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, when you have any input signal with a given SNR, the SNR will *only deteriorate* when you pass it through any active or passive circuitry such as amplifier stages.

However, when the signal occupies a limited portion of time or spectrum, you can use filters (digital or analog) to cut away the unused portions.

Still, when defining the signal's SNR only for its spectral and temporal domain, there is no way to increase this SNR. One can only attempt to deteriorate the native SNR by as little as possible (which equates to a *Noise Figure* of 0 dB).

The closest you can come to this (using op amps) is with a non-inverting amplifier, because it allows you to use no input resistor and small feedback resistors, without loading the signal source.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you. I was trying to figure out if the non-inverting was the way to go or not.

Answer (score 2):

With opamps, equivalent input voltage and current noise is taken in to consideration. In a single channel system, the noise will be amplified along with the signal. You can use lower resistor values in the feedback network to reduce Johnson (thermal) noise and reduce noise caused by in input current noise. If the source impedance is high, then choosing a low input current amplifier (JFET, MOS) is beneficial at the expense of slightly higher noise voltage.

Another thing to consider the the closed loop gain. Every stage in an opamp produces noise. You want to make sure that the gain is high enough so the later stages internal to the opamp don't contribute significantly to the noise issue.

If you parallel input stages you can get better signal to noise ratio if the noise is uncorrelated (true of thermal noise) by \$ \sqrt{n} \$, where *n* is the number of parallel stages. This technique is used in radio telescope, radar, and sonar arrays.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/353070850AN253.pdf

SNR improvements  depend on filtering , but in-band noise has the same gain + noise voltage and current *R